# Creating Nodes on click

Tags: nodes

I am trying to accomplish a certain requirement that is really seeming very confusing to me.

I have two content types for example, ListBank and List (both have pretty much the same fields i.e: title, notes, etc, etc..).

The ListBank content type holds some already created nodes.

Now what i am having trouble with is.. How can i show users the nodes existing in the ListBank content type (this part isn't that difficult as i think i can use a custom view to show a table for this).

But the real tough part i can't get around is when they select a node from the ListBank table and click a button called "add to my list" then it is suppose to create a new content type of List with the values of the selected ListBank node.

Any help would greatly be appreciated regarding this matter.

Comment: Why don't you create lists as [entity references](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) in user's profile? Seems a lot simpler, and able to solve your client's use case pretty well...

Comment: @Molot Thanks for the suggestion. I however cannot completely grasp how that would help me.. If possible could you please elaborate further. I am new drupal btw :)